# Capture RAW data from Ethernet using Wireshark

Tags: udp, wireshark, ethernet

I am new to Wireshark and capturing packets and all Stuff. Let me get it to the straight.

I have a hardware which outputs its data over Ethernet using a UDP Broadcast. I Can directly plug a Ethernet Cable to a In-line RJ-45 Coupler (attached to the hardware) and my PC Running Wireshark.

REQUIREMENTS : I need to Capture RAW Data which my hardware is broadcasting so that it can be given to other team so as to know the format in which it is providing for further post processing.

What I Did : Initially , I connected the Ethernet Cable from my home and Started capturing the packets which didn't make any sense to me.

Can you please point out if I am going in correct direction ? Sorry if its a very basic question, but raw data from the hardware is important for my further tasks....

Answer (score 0):

As far as **any** software can understand a wire you will always get a packet.  Between you (in front of a computer) and the cable in the in the RJ-45 jack sits a NIC (network interface controller, i.e. your network card).

Your Ethernet NIC will read the current on the cable (in [manchester encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) for ethernet) and synchronize itself to any Ehternet traffic on that cable.  What does "synchronizing" mane in there?  In front of any Ehternet traffic come 64 alternate bits of 0s and 1s which are meant to synchronize the clocks on both communicating NICs.  Without proper clock synchronization some data may be misinterpreted.

But why I am talking about clock synchronization?  Because if you want the data as RAW as it is on the cable you will not get it.  A NIC will never send any synchronization bit to the rest of the computer, therefore it is absolutely impossible to read exactly what is on the cable by using software.

---

On the other hand I find hard to believe you want the RAW data as RAW as that.  After the synchronization bits come an Ethernet encapsulated packed.  Yup, Ethernet uses packets.  They're link layer packets (layer 2 in OSI).

And `wireshark` gives you exactly that (in most cases, see note at the end for two exceptions to this rule): every Ehternet packet that the NIC understands, manages to sync, and manages to read without collision is sent to the kernel and then read by wireshark.  A cable has electrical interference and has no provision against collisions (it's just a piece of cooper!) therefore the NIC abstracts things like interferences and collisions.

I'll repeat it once more: After abstracting the synchronization bits, sender collisions (which turn the cable into one huge interference) and plain interferences; all that remains is a stream of packets, one after the other.

---

#### Extra Notes

NICs sometimes do ignore some Ethernet packets: packets that are not directed to their MAC.  This can be changed by enabling promiscuous mode (available in most NICs).  This is irrelevant for broadcast packets.

There are exception to the rule of wireshark getting all the traffic coming from the NIC:

- If the traffic comes incredibly quick, wireshark may drop out of kernel schedule and not see some packets.  It happens, nothign can be done about it.
- If you listen on all interfaces (as opposed to selecting a single interface to listen at), wireshark will strip the Ethernet (or Wifi) headers.  This is a wireshark hack needed to make output files uniform (and possible to be read by other applications).

---

TL;DR, wireshark output ([`pcap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap)) is pretty much just the stream of packets that it got from the NIC, one after the other.  That is as RAW as you can get with software.